# Create legend for heat map

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, legend

I have the following piece of code that colors words according to some value:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{blue!0}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!10}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!20}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!30}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!50}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!60}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!70}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!80}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!90}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!100}{\strut test}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Is it possible to create a scale/legend that shows what color is associated with what value of the color-strength? I.e., what I want is to make a scale like this one (but horizontal, not vertical):

[image]

---

When I run @marmot's solution and open the PDF, this is what I see:

[image]

My tex-distribution can only run with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}`, and not version 1.16 though. Can this be the cause of it?

I am opening it in Acrobat Reader DC

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for `\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone`? `/tikz/xscale=1.6` is a simple trick to adjust the width, but I don't know how wide it should be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\begin{document}
\colorbox{blue!0}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!10}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!20}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!30}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!50}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!60}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!70}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!80}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!90}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!100}{\strut test}

\noindent
\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[/tikz/xscale=1.6,
    colormap={whiteblue}{color=(white) color=(blue)},
    colorbar style={
        ticklabel style={
            font=\tiny,
            /pgf/number format/precision=3,
            /pgf/number format/relative*=4,
        },
    },
    colorbar horizontal,colormap access=const,
     point meta min=0,point meta max=100]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a vertical version thereof.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\begin{document}
\colorbox{blue!0}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!10}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!20}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!30}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!50}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!60}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!70}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!80}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!90}{\strut test}
\colorbox{blue!100}{\strut test}

\noindent
\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[/tikz/xscale=1.6,
    colormap={whiteblue}{color=(white) color=(blue)},
    colorbar style={
        ticklabel style={
            font=\tiny,
            /pgf/number format/precision=3,
            /pgf/number format/relative*=4,
        },
    },
    %colorbar horizontal,
    colormap access=const,
     point meta min=0,point meta max=100]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @N08 I don't know but it should be straightforward enough to try that out. Which version do you want to use? (And what prevents from updating your TeX distribution?)

Comment: @N08 And how do you compile? (This is really strange.)

Comment: I simply press F1 in TexMaker (F1 is Quick Build)

Comment: Your compilation path might have something to do with this. Try to ensure you use PDFLaTeX.

Comment: @OlegLobachev I am using PDFLaTeX, just double-checked

Comment: @OlegLobachev Do you know of an alternative method? I still have this issue

Answer (score 1):

See e.g. http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html (example number 299)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar horizontal]
\addplot[mesh,ultra thick] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```